# Datevalue out of daterange yet returning as true

Tags: google-sheets

Using this if/filter to compare the date in one tab which pulls date from a google forms link to a date range in another tab that is pulling the date range from a date dropdown. So I used the left and right to only pull the start and end date of the ranges which should result in true or false if the date is within this range, which in this case should not be... but it results in true, causing the Iferror/lookup to pull the date over cascading other commands.

```
=IF(FILTER('Raw Data'!C2:C>=DATEVALUE(LEFT(H2,7)),'Raw Data'!C2:C<=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(H2,8)),'Raw Data'!B2:B=B1)=true,IFERROR(LOOKUP(B1,'Raw Data'!O3,'Raw Data'!P3)),)
```

It seems to be working everywhere else... click below for images

[Sheets Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqMlv.png)  [Other Employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5WE7.png)  [Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AljAz.png)

Changed to this and it's working a bit better:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FILTER('Raw Data'!C2:C>=DATEVALUE(LEFT(H2,7)),'Raw Data'!C2:C<=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(H2,7)),'Raw Data'!B2:B=B1)=true,IFERROR(LOOKUP(B1,'Raw Data'!O1,'Raw Data'!P1)),),"No data found within pay range")
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include sample data and explain which sheet/cell this formula is in.

Comment: Please `**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.**`. [How do I ask a good question? - Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Users are unable to evaluate values displayed in a snapshot.